# why class-method need autorelease but instance-method not

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
+ (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

- (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  __weak UIView *view1 = [self getView];
  __weak UIView *view2 = [SampleViewController getView];

  NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2);    // view1 is null and view2 isn't null

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {   // Wait
    NSLog(@"Waiting");
  }

  NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2);    // view1 is null and view2 isn't null
}
```

i test it in viewDidLoad, it show the view1 is null and the view2 has value

Comment: change your NSLog, `NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2);`

Comment: sorry, it's my edit error in stackoverflow, but view1 is null in code

Comment: @zhkf : where are those __weak UIView *view1 = [self getView]; written ??

Comment: i test it in viewDidLoad

Comment: As far as I know both view1 and view2 will be non-nil in viewDidLoad. Once the control leaves the scope of viewDidLoad(like in viewDidAppear) both view1 and view2 will be nil.

Comment: thanks for reply, in my test view1 is null. so i confuse about whether the instance method return an autorelease object.

Comment: It's weird apple's compiler behaviour in debug. If you switch in release you will get null in both pointers.

Comment: in release it would optimize, so i think it may be not trustworthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
+ (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

- (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
    return view;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak UIView *view1;
    __weak UIView *view2;
    @autoreleasepool{
        view1 = [self getView];
        view2 = [SampleViewController getView];
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", view1, view2);
    };
}
```

Both view1 and view2 have values. autorelease-object will be added to the nearest autorelease pool, so instance-method also use autorelease. compiler maybe add the object returned by the class-method and the object returned by the instance-method in different autorelease-pool.

Answer (score 1):

They are both released but the static one is a bit later.

Try adding a bit more code:

```
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2); // You already have this
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2);
    });
```

The second print will occur 3 seconds later and should show both are null.

This is most likely a compile optimization on non-static method which does not use autorelease pool on your view. The static one is clearly on autorelease pool and will be deallocated in next run loop.

**EDIT:** The full code I tested on after creating a new project:

```
@implementation ViewController

+ (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

- (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak UIView *view1 = [self getView];
    __weak UIView *view2 = [ViewController getView];

    NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2);
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"%@, %@", view1, view2);
    });
}

@end
```

**To go a bit deeper:**

I created a view subclass to be able to debug a bit more:

```
@interface MyView: UIView
@end

@implementation MyView
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"Deallocated");
}
@end
```

So then we have:

```
+ (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
    return view;
}

- (UIView *)getView
{
    UIView *view = [[MyView alloc] init];
    return view;
}
```

I put a dealloc method so I can put a breakpoint init. The first hit was in `viewDidLoad` for instance called object. So that makes it clear that this object is not being on autorelease but the ARC system automatically added `[view release]` there. The second call is right after it and says it is from autorelease pool.

Comment: I don't think it's just because the static one is a bit later. In your code, seem like `view2` is released because it's out of `viewDidLoad` scope. Try to use `sleep(3)` instead of `dispatch_after` you will see it.

Comment: @trungduc Sleep will block the thread and will not allow the run loop to continue so autorelease pool will not kick in.

Comment: I have updated answer. You should check it. I use for loop instead of sleep.

Comment: @trungduc You updated the question and still you are blocking the run loop so no automatic autorelease may occur.

Comment: How can a for loop prevent automatic autorelease ?

Comment: @trungduc Simply. It is what it does. That is why you need to add another autorelease pool within the for loop when dealing with large data chunks. Anyway I updated the answer with yet another test. Do explore it.

Comment: thanks for answer, so, it jsut compiler optimization, dont know why it not optimize static method? and dont know why optimize non-static one? or how compiler optimize non-static one.

Comment: @Zhkf since others found out this does not occur on release configuration it might as well be a bug. Or it might have something to do with debugger as well. This should not effect your development though; using ARC you must treat all of these as being on autorelease pool and if some are optimized to be released instantly then even better.

Comment: @MaticOblak Custom class is great. Let add a `NSLog` at the end of `viewDidLoad` method. It will be printed before `Deallocated` is printed. Do you think `view2` is released because it's out of `viewDidLoad` scope?

Comment: @trungduc Scope has nothing to do with it. We only need to let the main run loop finish its cycle and the object is released. If you put this in another thread you could have a racing condition if the result would print null or not. It is how these things work; run loop can best be described as an endless loop, in each loop it will execute all the things it needs such as redisplay all windows, handle touch events, communication with the system... And somewhere along the road it will drain its autorelease pool. But this loop is stuck until all your code is dine including sleep and loops.

Comment: @MaticOblak Sorry if my persistence makes you uncomfortable but it doesn't make sense with me. If sleep and loops prevent `view2` from releasing, let swap 2 lines. Initializing `view1` after `view2`. Why `view1` is released and `view2` isn't?

Comment: @trungduc because one is on release pool and the other is not. If this was not ARC then the code would be `view1 = [self getView]; [view1 release] ... [[ViewController getView] autorelease]`. So the first one is released instantly while the second one will need to wait for the runloop to complete and will then be released by the autoreleased pool. I am not sure which part is confusing you here...

Comment: @MaticOblak Ok I got it.It makes sense now. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reason compiler adds `__autoreleasing` attribute for return pointer in DEBUG for class methods. I think this is bad, because it can lead to different behaviour in release. You should report this is as bug to Apple.